# Facing error when trying to set labels when using catplot from seaborn in Python?

Tags: python, seaborn

I am little new to catplots I was trying to set labels for catplot object as we do for sns.barplot but this throws the following error:

[Erorr image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaaeU.png)

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-f53ac3ccd85c> in <module>
      1 #g = sns.barplot(x="Sex",y="Survived",data=train)
      2 g=sns.catplot(x="Sex",y="Survived",data=train,kind="bar",height=4)
----> 3 g.set_ylabel("Survival Probability")

AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'set_ylabel'
```

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Although the example of the graph is different, you can customize the label names with `set_axis_labels(x_vars,y_vars)`.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise)

g.set_axis_labels('Time', 'ALL PLUSE')
```

[image]